# SQL DML Exercise 14

Tags: sql, select, sql-delete, dml

I have a problem I'm stuck on and I can't figure out how to get the correct query. So first off, this question is in reference to www.sql-ex.ru and its Exercise 10 in the DML section.

**Here is all the info:**

### Short database description "Ships":

The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database has the following relations:

```
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement) 
Ships(name, class, launched) 
Battles(name, date) 
Outcomes(ship, battle, result)
```

Ships in classes are arranged to a single project. A class is normally assigned the name of the first ship in the class under consideration (head ship); otherwise, the class name does not coincide with any ship name in the database. 
The Classes relation includes the class name, type (bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country where the ship was built, number of main guns, gun caliber (diameter of the gun barrel, in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation includes the ship name, its class name, and launch year. The Battles relation covers the name and date of a battle the ships participated; while the result of their participation in the battle (sunk, damaged, or unharmed - OK) is in the Outcomes relation. 
Notes: 1) Outcomes relation may include the ships not included in the Ships relation. 2) Sunk ship can not participate in battles after that.

### Here is exercise and hints:

- Delete the classes having less than three ships in database (taking into account Outcomes table).*

Hints to task #14

1. The class without the ships in the database also corresponds to the terms of the task such as 0 < 3.
2. Check the case when a class has 2 ordinary ships in Ships table and the head ship in Outcomes table, i.e. this class has 3 ships in DB.

### Here is my query:

```
delete from classes
where class not in (

select distinct c.class from classes c, ships s
where c.class = s.class
group by c.class
having count(name) >= 3
union
select distinct c.class from classes c, outcomes o
where c.class = o.ship
group by c.class
having count(ship) >= 3
union
select distinct s.class from ships s, outcomes o
where s.class = o.ship 
group by s.class
having count(name) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from classes 
where class not in (
select t.klas
from
(select class klas, count(class)no
from ships 
group by class

union all

select ship klas, count(ship)no
from outcomes
where ship not in (select s1.name from ships s1)
group by ship) t
group by t.klas
having sum(t.no) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

sql-ex dml ex 14

```
delete
from classes
where class in (
select c.class
from classes c
left join (
select name,class from ships -- classes from Ships
union
select ship,ship from outcomes -- lead classes from Outcomes
) so on c.class=so.class
group by c.class
having count(*)<3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM classes 
WHERE  class IN (SELECT class 
                 FROM   ships 
                 GROUP  BY class 
                 HAVING Count(NAME) < 3);
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see, I guess it's a bit late but I will explain for future. The second request select all the classes having less than three ships using the Count. And then we're looking for all the classes where our class "primary key" is the same as the class where there is less than three ships. Then we delete thos classes who matched. PS : Sorry for my english, hope it helps